# Why I cant delete element from collection (array) PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections

At this handler I delete NULL element:

```
if p_arr(i) is null then
    p_arr.delete(p_arr(i));
end if;
```

but null element still in collection. How can I correct this? 
The task is to sort elements in collection, but the condition is that there can be NULL in collection. I should delete them.

```
declare   
p_arr dbms_sql.Number_Table;   
i pls_integer;  

procedure do_sort(p_arr in out dbms_sql.Number_Table, p_asc in boolean 
default null, p_nulls_last in boolean default null) is   
x pls_integer;  
p_temp number;

begin  

for i in -1..p_arr.COUNT - 2 

loop   
  if p_arr(i) is null then
    p_arr.delete(p_arr(i));
  end if;        

end loop;  

end; 

begin   
p_arr(-1) := 0;   
p_arr(0) := -2;   
p_arr(1) := 10.1;   
p_arr(2) := null;    
p_arr(3) := 10.1;   
p_arr(4) := -1;  

do_sort(p_arr); 

i := p_arr.first;   

while i is not null loop   
  dbms_output.put_line('arr('||i||') = '||nvl(to_char(p_arr(i)), 
'null')||';');   
i := p_arr.next(i);   
end loop;   

end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are passing the element itself as the argument to the `delete`, rather than the index

`p_arr.delete(p_arr(i))`  is equivalent to `p_arr.delete(NULL)` - So it simply doesn't delete anything.

So, change it to `p_arr.DELETE(i)` it will work.